# cgid Permission denied in Foswiki

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied, foswiki

I have a foswiki installed, but I haven't been able to bootstrap it yet, because when I access the main page and click on one of the four links I get an internal server error, and I only find a log where it says that the cgid doesn't have permission for foswiki/bin/view, when the tools/fixpermissions script provided by foswiki itself has been executed. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

RHEL 9.3 system, with apache, SELinux in permissive, I have tried to access giving permissions 777 to the web root directory and subdirectories and I keep getting the same message "Internal server error" and in the log it keeps coming up that cgid does not have permissions for the foswiki/bin/view file.